# How to make vim parse my multi-line error message for the quickfix window?

Tags: vim

I want to run my app under vim using `make`, and I want the `quickfix` window display my errors.

So I have this format, which first starts with `Error:` and then filename, line and column separated by `:` and then on the next line, there's gonna be a multi line message with no special formatting, then the message will end with `ErrorEnd`.

So here's an example:

```
Error: /somefile/something/something.c:12:123
SOME MESSAGE 
ANOTHER HELPFUL MESSAGE
ANOTHER MESSAGE
ErrorEnd
```

I'm kinda lost in the documentation to how to make it match those lines. Everything seems so confusing and the examples aren't like this one. I know how to make it match the first line, but no idea how to make it match the next lines as the error message. So the question is what would be a errorformat string that could parse it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture multiple lines of text in the error message by using the `%+` prefix as described at `:help efm-ignore` in combination with the multi-line errorformat specifier `%E`, `%C`, `%Z`, etc. described at `:help errorformat-multi-line`. In your specific example, the following seems to work:

```
let &l:efm='%EError: %f:%l:%c,%-ZErrorEnd,%+C%.%#'
```

Note the `%+C` item which matches *any* text on the line and adds it to the error message. Note also how I had to put the `%-Z` item *before* this item for it to be used, since the first matching errorformat item will be used when parsing the line.

Comment: This is the only response that correctly answers the question and yet it (currently) has the lowest upvotes? Hmm.

Comment: Note Vim converts the source multi-line into a single-line entry for the quickfix list. As far as I can tell quickfix cannot display the original multi-line entry, only one that's been converted to single-line with the format string. Took me awhile to realize this distinction.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, parsing multi-line error messages for quickfix is difficult. I'm not even sure it's possible to parse the errors in such a block as *individual* errors.

A workaround that I've employed for unwieldy error output is to append a transformation step (typically using `sed`) to `'makeprg'` which converts the multi-line errors into traditional, one-line-per-error messages; something like

```
Error: /somefile/something/something.c:12:123 SOME MESSAGE
Error: /somefile/something/something.c:12:123 ANOTHER HELPFUL MESSAGE
Error: /somefile/something/something.c:12:123 ANOTHER MESSAGE
```

in your case.

Comment: Yeap, that's kinda what I'm doing. Was hoping there was more support for errors like this.

Answer (score 3):

From vim errorformat help page:

```
Multi-line messages             *errorformat-multi-line*

It is possible to read the output of programs that produce multi-line
messages, i.e. error strings that consume more than one line.  Possible
prefixes are:
    %E      start of a multi-line error message
    %W      start of a multi-line warning message
    %I      start of a multi-line informational message
    %A      start of a multi-line message (unspecified type)
    %>      for next line start with current pattern again |efm-%>|
    %C      continuation of a multi-line message
    %Z      end of a multi-line message
These can be used with '+' and '-', see |efm-ignore| below.

Using "\n" in the pattern won't work to match multi-line messages.

Example: Your compiler happens to write out errors in the following format
(leading line numbers not being part of the actual output):

     1  Error 275 
     2  line 42 
     3  column 3 
     4  ' ' expected after '--' 

The appropriate error format string has to look like this:
   :set efm=%EError\ %n,%Cline\ %l,%Ccolumn\ %c,%Z%m
```

Edit: Ah you mean multi-line error. Right. That's more difficult.