# Select relative range, ignoring invalid line numbers

Tags: vim, ex

I was wondering if there was a syntax for specifying a range of relative lines in vim/ex that does not give 'invalid range' and instead gets as many lines as it can.

Comment: There's nothing built in that will work on the command line. If you can narrow your use case, you might be able to accomplish something with a custom function (for example, [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) has a custom substitute command that could be modified to ignore range errors).

Comment: I just want to display the lines with their line numbers in ex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way, but you can resolve the relative ranges into absolute line numbers yourself, and then limit the range to the available lines with [`:help min()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#min%28%29) and [`:help max()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#max%28%29). So, for example, the following relative range:

```
:.-5,.+5 print
```

is equivalent to this:

```
:execute (line('.') - 5) . ',' . (line('.') + 5) 'print'
```

would be converted into this:

```
:execute max([1, (line('.') - 5)]) . ',' . min([line('$'), (line('.') + 5)]) 'print'
```

Answer (score 0):

My [CmdlineSpecialEdits plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5865) has (among many others) a `CTRL-G +` mapping that changes relative ranges like `.-5,.+5` to absolute line numbers and vice versa. It also corrects addressing out of bounds (<= 0 and larger than the last line number) and backwards ranges.